# Clicking on button does not direct me to the expected URL in Cypress

Tags: cypress

### The problem

There are 2 buttons at the end of the page on the app:

1. Back - which works perfectly in cypress. It returns user to the `/transportation` page
2. Review & Payment - does not take user to this page:  `/transportation/reservation/15802/payment` (15802 will change with each order)

It directs me here: `test.liberty.edu/transportation/reservation/store.htm`

### What I've tried

To click the Review & Payment button:

```js
cy.get('#trip-details-next').find('a').click()
cy.get('#trip-details-next').click()
cy.get('[data-top="2133.7999877929688"]').click()
```

To test if I've then reached the correct URL:

```js
cy.url().should('include', '/payment')
```

App code:

```js
<a href="/transportation" class="button" id="trip-details-back" tabindex="11">« Back</a>
<a href="#" class="button right" id="trip-details-next" tabindex="10" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Button', 'click', 'Reserve Shuttle')">Review & Payment »</a> ==$0
```

> CypressError: Timed out retrying: expected `'https://test.liberty.edu/transportation/reservation/store.htm'` to include `'/payment'`

Comment: <a href="#" class="button right" id="trip-details-next" tabindex="10" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Button', 'click', 'Reserve Shuttle')">Review &amp; Payment »</a> ==0

Comment: Does your app work properly? Do you see it redirecting in the Cypress test runner? If yes, maybe try passing a bigger timeout for `url`: `cy.url({ timeout: 10000 })`.